# Lighting-Input-Field - onchange

Tags: lightning-web-components, onchange

I have a lighting input field where onchange={handleChangeInc}

The handler is below.  This works fine but it also triggers when I save a record using submit.  Is there any way to avoid the same handler from being called onsubmit?  thanks!!

```js
handleChangeInc(event){
    let funding = event.target.value
    
    if(funding === 'A' || funding === 'B'){
        const evt = new ShowToastEvent({
            title: 'Required',
            message: 'If the group currently is either A or B… blah blah….',
            variant: 'warning',
            mode: 'sticky'
 
        });
        this.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }
}
```

Here is part of the html that applies:

```html
<!-- Record Edit Form-->       
<lightning-record-edit-form id="editform" 
                            record-id={selectedOppId} 
                            object-api-name="Opportunity" 
                            record-type-id={recordTypeId}
                            onsuccess={onSuccess} 
                            onsubmit={onSubmit} 
                            onerror={handleError}>
    <div class="slds-size--1-of-2">
        <lightning-input-field required field-name="Incumbent_Health_Funding__c" 
                                        class="oppfields" 
                                        onchange={handleChangeInc}> 
        </lightning-input-field>         
    </div>
```

Here is the onSubmit and onSuccess that get called when record-edit-form is submitted:

```js
onSubmit(event){
    this.loading = true ;
}
```

```js
onSuccess(event){
    this.loading = false ;
    
    if(event && event.detail && event.detail.id ){ 
        const oppid = event.detail.id;
        this.accid = event.detail.fields.AccountId.value; 
        this.selectedOppId = oppid;
            
        //message guideing user
        this.dispatchEvent(new ShowToastEvent({
            title: 'Opportunity Updated',
            message:  'You have updated the Opportunity',
            variant: 'success'
        })); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `onsubmit` another event on DOM, can you show the html file?

Comment: I updated the question with the relevant HTML.  onSubmit is the method called when the record is saved.  thanks!

Comment: I still dont get it how `handleChangeInc` is getting called, I think you might be trying to change the value of the input field and the onChange gets called then. Can you share the element where onChange is written

Comment: The onchange gets called when I update the field... but then, when I submit the record (its a new record so its getting created) its calling the handleChangeInc again for some reason.  The only place the handleChangeInc is getting called by code is on the input field. I posed that above.  I am not sure why handleChangeInc is getting called onsubmit.  thanks!

Comment: Issue might be caused because inside onSuccess you set selectedOppId which is in fact your record-id for rcord-edit-form.